# Arcpy returning empty string when run in script, but not when run in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

A part of my script where I extract the view definition is returning an empty string when I run it, but if I run the same exact code in ArcGIS, I get the correct return.

It is only for the desc.whereClause return, the others such as desc.name, desc.nameString are working correctly.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

```
mxdpath = r"C:\...\blah.mxd"
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdpath)
dataFrames = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapDoc)
for i in range(0,len(dataFrames)):
    lyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapDoc,"",dataFrames[i])
    for j in range(0,len(lyrs)):
        if lyrs[j].isFeatureLayer:
            desc = arcpy.Describe(lyrs[j])
            print "Name string:  " + desc.nameString
            print "Where Clause:  " + desc.whereClause
```

This code returns a blank u'' for desc.whereClause, however the same code will produce something like 'objectId = 1' if I run it in the python app inside ArcMap Desktop

Comment: When executing from the python Window in ArcMap, are you using `mxdpath = 'CURRENT'`?

Comment: import arcpy? Have you already?

Comment: Try lyrs[j].definitionQuery to get the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead(last section of your code):

```
if lyrs[j].isFeatureLayer:
    print lyrs[j].name
    print lyrs[j].definitionQuery
```

Also import arcpy at the beginning if you haven't yet.